# Scala-Play: How to create a Component with access to Application lifecycle events?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Scala-Play 2.5.x application that is actually a "Services Container" meaning under some service specification the user can hot-deploy services and they can be executed etc. Some of the services need common functionality like e.g. connection to a time-series database e.g. KDB.

I'd like to define in my Play application components that will know when the application starts and ends so they can do initialization and shutdown of their resources. I also need their "state" for example KDB connections to be made accessible to the deployed services in a seamless way i.e.

- A request to execute a service is intercepted
- The service "requirements" are inspected e.g. service X needs access to specific KDB connections
- The service is generically instantiated and executed injecting the KDB connection required using IoC.

I have everything described above except this concept of "Component". I checked out Play books that talk about a previous `play.api.Plugin` trait that was a good start i.e. it had `onStart` `onEnd` etc. but it seems that this interface is gone in 2.5.x. Then I checked out how to create application Modules but all I see is an subclass of Module that overrides `def bindings` that does a bunch of IoC but nothing else. How can I cover my use-case of an application Component that has access to play web application lifecycle events and that can provide some state to specific requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual: [ScalaDependencyInjection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) could this help:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import javax.inject._
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

@Singleton
class MessageQueueConnection @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {
  val connection = connectToMessageQueue()
  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    Future.successful(connection.stop())
  }

  //...
}
```

This is the way for Play 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: Ok wow very simple way yes. Therefore, I would basically inject the `MessageQueueConnection` wherever I need access to the connection in my controller classes ...

Comment: That's the way I would do, yes.